# SceneKit with SpriteKit intersection of nodes

Tags: sprite-kit, intersection, scenekit

Hi I want to have a selection box on my game. 
I assume that making with 'SpriteKit' overlay is the easiest way to do
But is there any API to detect intersection of 'SKShapeNode' 
and 'SCNNode' (Ignoring the Z axis ofcourse) ?

What have I tried to do:
`_unitsArray` is an array of `SCNNodes` that I wish to have they're bounding boxes in a `SKScene`

```
                   for (SCNNode * node in _unitsArray)
                   {
                       SCNVector3 min = SCNVector3Zero;
                       SCNVector3 max = SCNVector3Zero;

                       [node getBoundingBoxMin:&min max:&max];

                       NSLog(@"Min Before %lf, %lf, %lf", min.x, min.y, min.z);
                       NSLog(@"Max Before %lf, %lf, %lf", max.x, max.y, max.z);


                       min = vector3Multiply(min, node.scale);
                       max = vector3Multiply(max, node.scale);


                       //Lets Get Nodes's Position
                       SCNVector3 position = node.position;
                       NSLog(@"Position =  %lf, %lf, %lf", position.x, position.y, position.z);

                       SCNView * view = (SCNView *)self.view;
                       SCNVector3 posinView = [view projectPoint:position];

                       NSLog(@"Position in View =  %lf, %lf, %lf", posinView.x, posinView.y, posinView.z);

                                                 min = [view projectPoint:min];
                       max = [view projectPoint:max];
                       NSLog(@"Min Scaled + Projected %lf, %lf, %lf", min.x, min.y, min.z);
                       NSLog(@"Max Scaled + Projected %lf, %lf, %lf", max.x, max.y, max.z);

                       CGFloat width    =  max.x - min.x;
                       CGFloat height   =  max.y - min.y;
                       CGRect maybeRect = CGRectMake(posinView.x - width /2, posinView.y - height /2, width, height);

                       SKSpriteNode * Snode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor yellowColor] size:maybeRect.size];
                       [Snode setPosition:CGPointMake(posinView.x, posinView.y)];
                       [self addChild:Snode];
}
```

For some reason the Snode is twice bigger than expected :-O 
Also i don't know what to do with the returned Z
Can some1 shed some light ?

Comment: You may be asking for too much,  the overlay should be treated as an overlay,  SpriteKit and SceneKit uses 2 different technologies for collision detection,  so I doubt there is a way they will work together

Comment: how do you need help on this?

Comment: I have a Rectangle on my SKOverlay view I want to hit test intersection with my SCNNodes I will update a Question in just 5 mins

Comment: if it is just a rectangle, then have an invisible SKNode that has the rectangle physics body the size of your scene node

Comment: @Knight0fDragon i am struggling to convert `SCNNode` boundingBox to a 2d view coordinates

Comment: I do not know too much about SceneKit to get you that far,  is there not a frame property you can use?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon unfortunately nope :(

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I did the opposite way from SKScene to SCNScene, but can't do from SCNScene to SKScene :)